# How to define keywords in helpndoc using api in script editor

Tags: api, keyword, pascalscript, helpndoc

I want to create keywords in HelpNDoc using api script editor. But, I could not find how to define parameter of function `HndKeywords.CreateKeyword`. Without passing any value to function, it create New keyword. But, I want to set text, `href` and `data-related` object informations.

```
HndKeywords.CreateKeyword;
```

Output:_keywords.json

```
[{ "id": "B3BF561185624A4685FB01E93FE5ED87", "parent" : "#", "text": "New keyword", "a_attr": {"href": "#", "data-related": "[]"} }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that, there is no way to add caption and data-related information when we are creating the keyword.

> ```
> function SetKeywordCaption(const aKeywordId: string; const sNewCaption: string): string;
> function AssociateTopicWithKeyword(const aTopicId: string; const  aKeywordId:string): Boolean;
> ```

In order to edit the keyword caption, I have to use the function `SetKeywordCaption`, which needs keyword id. For that, I get the keyword list using function `GetKeywordList();` and it returns an array. I get the last element numeric id from that array which is a newly inserted keyword. Then, access the `aKeywordList` array using last element array id and add `.Id` which will retrieve id of that keyword. Then, Using keyword id with function `SetKeywordCaption`, able to edit keyword caption.

In order to add data-related information, I have use function `AssociateTopicWithKeyword` which needs the `topic id` and `keyword id`. I get topic list using function `GetTopicList`. I get topic id of five(`topic_array[(5-1)].ID`) and sixth topic(`topic_array[(6-1)].ID`). Then, have used function `AssociateTopicWithKeyword` to link keyword to topics.

Call helpndoc function:

> Object.function

ex (`HndKeywords.CreateKeyword;`)

```
var new_keyword                :=HndKeywords.CreateKeyword;
var aKeywordList                =HndKeywords.GetKeywordList() ;
//get keyword added last
var newlyaddedkeyword_array_id  =length(aKeywordList) - 1 ;
var newlyaddedkeyword__id       =aKeywordList[newlyaddedkeyword_array_id].Id;
var edit_keywordcaption         =HndKeywords.SetKeywordCaption(newlyaddedkeyword__id, "Edited keyword");
var topic_array=HndTopics.GetTopicList; 
var keywordtopics         =HndTopicsKeywords.AssociateTopicWithKeyword(topic_array[4].ID,newlyaddedkeyword__id);//parameter : topic id and keyword id
var keywordtopics2          =HndTopicsKeywords.AssociateTopicWithKeyword(topic_array[5].ID,newlyaddedkeyword__id);
```

See: [`HndKeywords` - Properties and methods for keywords](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/HelpNDocAPImethods.html#HndKeywords)

Comment: I suggest that you add a little xplanation along with your code snippet. I know it is fairly self explanatory but the SO team tend to dislike answers that are simply "code". This is why I atleast added a link to the official documentation for the `HndKeywords` API.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer ... to make it clear to other researchers a solution was found.

Comment: This can be greatly simplified: `HndKeywords.CreateKeyword` returns the newly created keyword's ID. So you don't need to get a list of keywords afterwards and simply use `HndKeywords.SetKeywordCaption(new_keyword, "Edited keyword")` to set the caption of the newly created keyword.